# Faster way to return pandas series with True if column value is min in groupby object and False otherwise

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas df, and am trying to return a pandas series filled with bools for each row where the it is True if the value is the min in its respective groupby object, and False otherwise.

Using transform works fine.

`df.groupby(grouping_column)[value_column].transform(lambda x:x == min(x))`

But it is painfully slow. I've looked over the docs and non of the other groupby methods seem to solve this. Does anyone have any ideas? Perhaps sorting then taking `first()` and comparing that to all other entries in the group? Btw, i would like to preserve the same indexing as in the original `df`. Thanks!

Comment: `df['value_column'] == df.groupby(grouping_column)['value_column'].transform('min')` should be a little faster.

Comment: wow! It's like >400x faster. is that purely because it's no longer using a python engine because of the `lambda` i originally had?

Comment: In short: Yes!!!